# How can I dynamically display what appears in the modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, debugging

The type of food selected shows up in the modal successfully upon clicking the appropriate button if I write in between `<Modal>`

```
<p>{this.state.cTaco}</p>
<p>{this.state.bTaco}</p>
<p>{this.state.cBurrito}</p>
```

But instead of writing it out 1 by 1, I want it to display dynamically using some sort of map or loop.

With my current code, it's displaying all the names of the items in the object on the modal and not the actual food name.

```
cTacoClicked

cTaco

bTacoClicked

bTaco

cBurritoSelected

cBurrito
```

It should display (again, it does display it like this if I write out the states 1 by 1):

```
Chicken Taco

Beef Taco

Chicken Burrito
```

How can I correctly use a loop to make this happen dynamically.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

import Aux from '../../../../hoc/Aux';
import FoodButton from '../FoodButtons/FoodButton';
import CheckoutButton from '../CheckoutButton/CheckoutButton';
import axios from '../../../../axios-foodChosen';

import { CLOSE_MODAL, OPEN_MODAL } from "../../../../store/action/NoNameAction";

class TacoTypes extends Component {
    state = {
        items: {
            cTacoClicked: false,
            cTaco: '',

            bTacoClicked: false,
            bTaco: '',

            cBurritoSelected: false,
            cBurrito: ''
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        // for modal
        Modal.setAppElement('body');
    }

    chickenTaco() {
        // modal
        const cTacoSelected = "Chicken Taco";
        this.setState({cTacClicked: true, cTaco: cTacoSelected});
    }

    beefTaco() {
        // modal
        const bTacoSelected = "Beef Taco";
        this.setState({bTacoClicked: true, bTaco: bTacoSelected});
    }

    chickenBurrito() {
        // modal
        const cBurritoSelected = "Chicken Burrito";
        this.setState({cBurritoSelected: true, cBurrito: cBurritoSelected });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <FoodButton clicked={() => this.chickenTaco()} label={"Chicken Taco"}/>
                <FoodButton clicked={() => this.beefTaco()} label={"Beef Taco"}/>
                <FoodButton clicked={() => this.chickenBurrito()} label={"Chicken Burrito"}/>

                <CheckoutButton clicked={() => this.props.openModalRedux()}/>

                <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen}>
                    <p>
                        {
                            Object.keys(this.state.items).map(i => (
                                <p>{i}</p>
                            ))
                        }
                    </p>
                    <button onClick={() => this.props.closeModalRedux()}>Close</button>
                </Modal>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        // props for modal
        isOpen: state.global.isModalOpen,
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        // Modal handlers
        openModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: OPEN_MODAL}),
        closeModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: CLOSE_MODAL})
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TacoTypes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently just using the keys of the `items` object. You want to get the value that the keys have in the `state` object.

```
<Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen}>
  <p>
    {Object.keys(this.state.items).map(key => (
      <p key={key}>{this.state[key]}</p>
    ))}
  </p>
  <button onClick={() => this.props.closeModalRedux()}>Close</button>
</Modal>
```

Comment: ah, I tried this already before, but it isn't working for some reason :(

Comment: @sp92 Excuse me, I misunderstood. Try the updated answer.

Comment: Alright, now this works!  I really had the same exact thing you had before and it was driving me insane how come it didn't work.  Thank you, Tholle :D!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very messy. Your code structure is fixed, meaning that each taco type has to be declared individually and in different methods...

The main problem with your code is you have `items` in your state which you read from, but in the `*Taco()` methods and the `chickenBurrito()` method you set `this.state.cTaco` (for example) instead of `this.state.items.cTaco`.

But your code in general *could* and *should* be improved. How about instead of an individual method for each taco type you do the following:

Change your state structure to:

```
this.state = {
  selectedItem: '',
};
```

And declare the following object in your constructor:

```
this.items = {
  // If you'll have more attributes for each item, it's best that you set
  // each item as an object with a name and the other attributes.
  chickenTaco: 'Chicken Taco',
  beefTaco: 'Beef Taco',
  chickenBurrito: 'Chicken Burrito',
};
```

And then you can have one method instead of three (or however many items you have):

```
selectItem(item) {
  this.setState({selectedItem: item});
}
```

So now your Modal's contents will look like this:

```
{this.items.map(item => (<p key={item}>{item}</p>)}
```

Far cleaner. This way the items are dynamic, and you can easily add attributes and items. In a real life use you'd probably get this information from the backend, where you can't anticipate which methods you need to create per items, or how many items you'll have (if any).