# How can I optimize my code in a way where only one method is required (if possible)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, optimization

I'm trying to optimize my code in a way where I wouldn't need 3 different methods (or however many I decide to include in the future) to safely store the users selection of a food type in the database whenever the user clicks the appropriate button.

I've tried numerous different ways but my code keeps breaking and I end up just chasing my own tail around.  I feel like it's inefficient to optimize because each food type is different which means we would need different methods to store different foods in the database.

Side note: The modal works fine in terms of the user selection appearing one by one upon clicking on the food type desired.  I want my code to be optimized in a way where in the future, I can add a delete feature if the user decides not to want that particular food anymore (but I can deal with that later).

(I'm a noob with react, forgive me please =D)

So is it possible to make my code way cleaner than it already is?

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

import Aux from '../../../../hoc/Aux';
import FoodButton from '../FoodButtons/FoodButton';
import CheckoutButton from '../CheckoutButton/CheckoutButton';
import axios from '../../../../axios-foodChosen';

import { CLOSE_MODAL, OPEN_MODAL } from "../../../../store/action/NoNameAction";

class TacoTypes extends Component {
    state = {
        items: {
            cTacoClicked: false,
            cTaco: '',

            bTacoClicked: false,
            bTaco: '',

            cBurritoSelected: false,
            cBurrito: ''
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        // for modal
        Modal.setAppElement('body');
    }

    chickenTaco() {
        // modal
        const cTacoSelected = "Chicken Taco";
        this.setState({cTacClicked: true, cTaco: cTacoSelected});

        // firebase
        let name = "Chicken Taco";
        axios.post('./chosen.json', { name })
            .then(response => {
                console.log("chicken taco check firebase");
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    beefTaco() {
        // modal
        const bTacoSelected = "Beef Taco";
        this.setState({bTacoClicked: true, bTaco: bTacoSelected});

        // firebase
        let name = "Beef Taco";
        axios.post('./chosen.json', { name })
            .then(response => {
                console.log("beef taco check firebase");
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })

    }

    chickenBurrito() {
        // modal
        const cBurritoSelected = "Chicken Burrito";
        this.setState({cBurritoSelected: true, cBurrito: cBurritoSelected });

        // firebase
        let name = "Chicken Burrito";
        axios.post('./chosen.json', { name })
            .then(response => {
                console.log("chicken burrito check firebase");
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <FoodButton clicked={() => this.chickenTaco()} label={"Chicken Taco"}/>
                <FoodButton clicked={() => this.beefTaco()} label={"Beef Taco"}/>
                <FoodButton clicked={() => this.chickenBurrito()} label={"Chicken Burrito"}/>

                <CheckoutButton clicked={() => this.props.openModalRedux()}/>

                <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen}>
                    <p>
                        {Object.keys(this.state.items).map(key => (
                            <p key={key}>{this.state[key]}</p>
                        ))}
                    </p>
                    <button onClick={() => this.props.closeModalRedux()}>Close</button>
                </Modal>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        // props for modal
        isOpen: state.global.isModalOpen,
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        // Modal handlers
        openModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: OPEN_MODAL}),
        closeModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: CLOSE_MODAL})
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TacoTypes);
```

Comment: The only difference between the code for each taco type is the name of the taco. So just create on single food function and insert the taco name as a parameter. And then store all tacos in an array instead of having a store with properties for each seperate taco type. It should not matter What the user buys, you should be able to change tacos to fruits without changing anything related to inserting into the database.

Comment: I happen to be the one that commented on the cleaness of this code, and I stand by [my suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800782/how-can-i-dynamically-display-what-appears-in-the-modal/51800829#51800829). Although, this kind of post might fit better on [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), another Stack Exchange website.

Comment: @NonameSL yeah, I remember.  I tried your suggestion (thanks for it!).  It worked, but, only one food type at a time appears on the modal (never allowed more than 1 food type in the modal).  I wanted in a way where all the buttons that user clicked appears in the modal.

Comment: @sp92 I see what you mean. You could modify it so instead of `selectedItem` you'd have `selectedItems` which would be an array that you push & pull from. I'll post an answer with the full code right now.

Comment: @NonameSL ah ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've narrowed it down to these main problems:

- You're declaring constants in your state. It's bad practice and there's no reason for it. The state is supposed to include dynamic variables that change. You shouldn't include constants like food names in there.
- Your code isn't [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself). You should find ways to generalize your code. For example, if your three methods do the same thing but with different foods, you could pass the food you want to do the action on as a variable and have one method that does the same.

Here's how your code could look like applying these principles (I didn't include *all* your code for comfort):

```
//Imports, blah blah blah
class TacoTypes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        //It's common practice to declare your state in the constructor.

        this.state = {
            selectedItems: [],
        };

        //Constant item names
        this.items = {
            chickenTaco: 'Chicken Taco',
            beefTaco: 'Beef Taco',
            chickenBurrito: 'Chicken Burrito',
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        // for modal
        Modal.setAppElement('body');
    }
    selectFood(food) {
        this.setState(state => {
            //Dynamically setting state to avoid race conditions
            let selected = state.selectedItems;
            if(!selected.includes(food)) selected.push(food);
            return {selectedItems: selected};
        });

        //Do whatever with firebase here...
        //You can get the name using this.items[food]
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                {Object.keys(this.items).map(key => (
                    //Keeping our code DRY, we dynamically create the food buttons.
                    //React will throw a warning if we don't supply a unique key prop when dynamically creating variables using loops.
                    <FoodButton key={key} clicked={() => this.selectFood(key)} label={this.items[key]} />
                ))}

                <CheckoutButton clicked={() => this.props.openModalRedux()}/>

                <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen}>
                    <p>
                        {
                            //According to your comments I assume you want to display the items
                            //selected only, unlike what you originally coded:
                            this.state.selectedItems.map(key => (
                                <p key={key}>{this.items[key]}</p>
                            ))
                        ))}
                    </p>
                    <button onClick={() => this.props.closeModalRedux()}>Close</button>
                </Modal>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
}
//Include the rest of your code here
```

Notice the comments along the code as they explain my actions and will help you understand the rationale behind what I'm doing.

Comment: never learned so much in one post, thanks so much man.  I would give you a hug if I could.

Comment: The equivalent of a hug on SO would be an upvote ;) Glad you learned more!